# How to get rid of "Type Safety" warning for generic builder?

Tags: java, generics

I realize a immutable composite using the builder pattern and an abstract base class for both the elements and the builders. To reduce need for casting and to get the code for the elements as concise as possible I create the base classes using generics. I get one warning I do not understnad. Please explain why the warning is shown and how I can get rid of it (WITHOUT using @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") of course)?

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
abstract public class JElement<J extends JElement<J>> {
    abstract protected <B extends AbstractBuilder<J, B>> B newBuilder();

    abstract public static class AbstractBuilder<J extends JElement<J>, B extends AbstractBuilder<J, B>> {

        public AbstractBuilder() {
        }

        abstract public J build();
    }
}

public class JClass extends JElement<JClass> {
    JClass(Builder builder) {
    }

    @Override
    protected Builder newBuilder() {
        return new Builder(this);
    }

    public static class Builder extends JElement.AbstractBuilder<JClass, Builder> {
        public Builder(JClass jClass) {
        }

        @Override
        public JClass build() {
            return new JClass(this);
        }
    }
}
```

The warning  is at the return value of JClass.newBuilder:

> Type safety: The return type JClass.Builder for newBuilder() from the
>   type JClass needs unchecked conversion to conform to B from the type
>   JElement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `B` type parameter for your `newBuilder()` method is not bound to anything:

```
abstract protected <B extends AbstractBuilder<J, B>> B newBuilder();
```

This method signature allows the user to specify *any* class `B extends AbstractBuilder<J, B>` as the return type, not just the:

```
public static class Builder extends JElement.AbstractBuilder<JClass, Builder> {
```

class that you defined.  There are two effective solutions to the problem:

1) Bind `B` to `J` in `J`'s class definition, by changing the declaration to:

```
 abstract public class JElement<J extends JElement<J>, B extends JElement.AbstractBuilder<J, B>> {
```

2) My preferred solution, change the abstract method signature to:

```
 abstract protected AbstractBuilder<J, ?> newBuilder();
```

Comment: Thenk you. Your prefered solution (2) works very well for me.